# not getting what heroku logs are saying

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have deployed app on Heroku but app is not working( I got this message on browser "We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.") when I checked log I found below message.Can anyone tell me what is the meaning of it?

```
Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2018-01-20T10:54:29.710117+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2018-01-20T10:54:29.710722+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2018-01-20 10:54:29 +0000 ===
2018-01-20T10:54:29.710724+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2018-01-20T10:54:29.710881+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2018-01-20T10:54:29.837650+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2018-01-20T10:54:39.660402+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 38017 -e production`  
2018-01-20T10:54:45.686497+00:00 app[web.1]: DEPRECATION WARNING: `config.serve_static_files` is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1.
2018-01-20T10:54:45.686528+00:00 app[web.1]: Please use `config.public_file_server.enabled = true` instead.
2018-01-20T10:54:45.686586+00:00 app[web.1]:  (called from block in <top (required)> at /app/config/environments/production.rb:6)
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277792+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277810+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:38017
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277812+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277818+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.10.0 (ruby 2.3.4-p301), codename: Russell's Teapot
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277813+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277819+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 16
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277908+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:38017
2018-01-20T10:54:47.277820+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2018-01-20T10:54:47.278132+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2018-01-20T10:54:47.817688+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2018-01-20T10:56:14.896122+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-peak-94323.herokuapp.com request_id=85b8c594-2d92-4e76-9060-01caf2307a44 fwd="45.115.104.19" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=268ms status=500 bytes=1735 protocol=https
2018-01-20T10:59:49.774607+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=salty-peak-94323.herokuapp.com request_id=d60e4280-6d74-42ff-93e4-5a47dcc3bc93 fwd="45.115.104.19" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=41ms status=500 bytes=1735 protocol=https
```

Answer (score 0):

The logs says `DEPRECATION WARNING: config.serve_static_files is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1, Please use  config.public_file_server.enabled = true instead`, So try to change this to what it is saying, Although i believe it is just a warning and it should not break your app but i found a related question to this one, [Here it is](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38389231/i-get-this-error-when-i-run-heroku-run-rake-dbmigrate-in-production), Hope it helps

Comment: It's already done but still app is breaking, don't know what is happening here.